# How to trigger email when container changes

Tags: azure

Is there a way in Azure to trigger an email send when for some reason the docker container changes? The containers are running in App Service Environments. When I have Jenkins change the container, this is no issue. However, there are times when a person manually changes the container and then no email is sent. Our QA staff are then never informed. Thanks!